# Knockout JS - how to detect element that triggered blur?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-events

I'm trying to update an input value on conditional blur in Knockout - basically I want the element not to trigger a value update when a specific element triggers the blur. I know I can watch `mousedown` on every element on the document and determine what was last clicked, but seems a bit excessive. Any other work around anyone can think of?

```
<input class="edit" data-bind="value: title, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterKey:     $root.stopEditing, selected: editing, event: { blur: $root.checkEditing }">
```

The code I was trying to achieve to pull this off isn't working with `document.activeElement`.

```
self.checkEditing = function( item, event ) {
        if (document.activeElement == $('a.cancel')) {

            // revert to previous title, aka cancel the editing
            item.title(item.previousTitle);
            item.editing( false );

        } else {
                            // this will update value with whatever was typed right before the blur
            item.editing( false );

            if ( !item.title().trim() ) {
                self.remove( item );
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: your handler function is passed in an 'event' object. You can use event.target to determine the element

Comment: The 'event' target in this case is always the input.

Comment: your `if` will never pass. A jQuery object can't be equal to a DOM element. Maybe you meant `if ($(document.activeElement).is("a.cancel"))`

Comment: True! That was just for demonstration purposes - should have double checked that before I posted. In this case though the document.activeElement is always returning the body tag.

Comment: By default, `a` isn't a "focusable" element. If you give the `a` a `tabindex` attribute, does it work?

Comment: Sadly, 'tabindex' didn't work. Dang!

Comment: Any chance you could set up a simple [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: As I was setting up the fiddle I realized the issue. I needed to set setTimeout for the document.activeElement to return the currently focused element. Check out this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hUA9v/5/). Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like to appropriately capture the element that has triggered the blur, setTimeout has to be used. After the blur is processed, setTimeout ensures that the focused element has become available.

For example:

The input:

```
<input class="edit" data-bind="value: title, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', selected: editing, event: { blur: $root.checkEditing, click: $root.editItem }">
```

The method that checks the active element after blur:

```
   self.checkEditing = function( item, event ) {

        setTimeout(function(){

            console.log("The active element is: " + document.activeElement)

            // check if the user selected cancel
            if ($(document.activeElement).is("a.cancel")) {

                // revert to previous title
                item.title(item.previousTitle);
            }
        });

        item.editing( false );

        if ( !item.title().trim() ) {
            self.remove( item );
        }

    };
```

Full fiddle demonstrating this is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hUA9v/5/