# Knockout Delay when updating Observables (w fiddle)

Tags: knockout.js

I have a list of items that can be edited one at a time.  When editing, if the user clicks anywhere outside of the input EXCEPT for a cancel button, the data should save.

I have this working, but there's a slight delay in canceling the save because the "blur" event is registered before the Cancel button click.  I was wondering how I can eliminate this delay (perhaps by somehow detecting the Cancel first), or if I should rework the way this is currently scripted.  I'm open to any suggestions.

VM Code:

```
function PersonViewModel(name) {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.editing = ko.observable(false);
    self.oldName = ko.observable();      
    // Behaviors
    self.edit = function() { 
        self.oldName(self.name());
        self.editing(true) 
    }
    self.save = function() { 
        self.editing(false) 
    }
    self.cancel = function() { 
        self.name(self.oldName());
        self.editing(false) 
    }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.selected = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var selected = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (selected) element.select();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel("Bert Bertington"));
```

View:

```
<button data-bind="click: cancel">CANCEL</button>
<p>
    Name: 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasfocus: editing, selected: editing, event: {blur: save}" />
</p>
<p><em>Click the name to edit it; click elsewhere to apply changes.</em></p>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RnCUd/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do something with checking the new active element to see if it is the cancel button via `document.activeElement` in your `save` function, although it does not appear to work in JSFiddle's frames (see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031426/knockout-js-how-to-detect-element-that-triggered-blur)).

My suggestion though would be to switch to having an edit icon/button next to the text and follow the pattern described here for cancelling and accepting edits: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

The advantage to the methodology described above involving an explicit edit button is that your editing functionality is more easily discoverable by the end user and does not require any instruction text. See **[this UX.StackExchange post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/24620/how-to-tell-the-user-to-click-to-edit-data/24622#24622)** on the problem with your current pattern.

Comment: I currently have an edit button - that's the only way this becomes editable in production.  I just reused this fiddle to quickly demonstrate the problem I'm having with canceling.  I'll give document.activeElement a shot, thanks :)

Comment: @RobVious If that doesn't work and you already have an edit button, then I might suggest flipping the paradigm demonstrated in your jsfiddle where you cache the old value, and instead separate out the new value like so: http://jsfiddle.net/RnCUd/22/

Comment: I haven't been able to get document.activeElement to work.  I updated your fiddle to demonstrate the problem again: http://jsfiddle.net/RnCUd/23/  See how cancel is not working there?  I'd like to save if anything BUT that cancel button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way, pretty sure you've been answering my questions all week :P

Comment: @RobVious no problem haha. I thought it might have something to do with JSFiddle's frames, but it doesn't seem to work for me either locally. Blur may not be a usable trigger in this case it seems.

Comment: @RobVious it looks like this might be fixed in the upcoming v2.3 of knockout: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/698